# Sharp Distance Sensor

Tags: sensor, troubleshooting

I have a Sharp GP2D120 which is a distance sensor for the range 40mm-300mm. Reading the [datasheet](http://www.active-robots.com/products/sensors/sharp/gp2d120.pdf) the output voltage should change from quite high to very low. I cannot get this change to happen. The most i can get the output voltage to move by is about 0.1V and its averaging about 0.3V at a distance of about 50-60mm. Has anyone got any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: @community probably needs tag help

Comment: Yeah i didn't know what to tag it as so feel free to edit them.

Comment: The object needs to be reflective, what is it in your case?

Comment: Its in a Micromouse maze to the UK standards. They say: 
1.2. The side of the micromouse maze walls shall be white, and the top of the walls shall normally be red. The floor of the micromouse maze shall be made of MDF and finished with a matt variety of black paint (blackboard paint). The coating on the top and side of the wall shall be selected to reflect, and the coating on the floor shall be selected to absorb, visible and infra-red light.

Comment: @Dean - Requests for clarification: What is the input impedance of your voltage sensing circuit, what is the power supply current (and voltage), what are you using as a reflective object, what distances are you trying to measure, and does an IR sensitive camera (any unfiltered camera/cell phone will work) pick up anything from the sensor's IR LED?

Comment: BTW, Micromouse is sweet!  I've always wanted to try that.

Comment: @reemrevnivek I have an iPhone which does as do the rest of my family so it won't detect the IR. How would I find out the input impedance? I have the output from the distance sensor going straight in to an ADC in a PIC.

Comment: @reemrevnivek its Alevel project to create a micromouse its nearly finished :D jsut getting the software developed on the PIC then its ready to roll.:D

Comment: I also have a test maze so it is a maze wall that im reflected the IR at for testing.

Comment: @Dean re: input impedance - Straight into an ADC input should be a very high impedance (you can get it from the datasheet), I was wondering if you were using a resistive divider that was too high, or a mis-configured filter circuit or something. (You may want some filtering for this)

Comment: @reemrevnivek it says this: 
The maximum recommended impedance for analog sources is 10 kΩ. 
Is that what your talking about with input impedance? Here is the datasheet for the PIC im using:
http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/41291F.pdf

Comment: I might have wired it up wrong just going to check and will report back. This might explain why its not working :/

Comment: @Dean, if you want the question deleted you should be able to. I see no harm in keeping this question, it may have been a basic solution, but it is something someone can pull off of their search results and find our site to ask more detailed questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the wires are wired correctly from the JST on the sensor to your project. Check the order on that particular model looking at the connector with the sensor facing away from you the output pin is the left one, middle is ground and right is VCC. Check these where you connect them to your project. As having them connected the wrong way round could damage them and will give you this reading.